# How can I make diagram labels vertical in a WeChat Mini-Program?

Tags: javascript, canvas, diagram, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I am drawing a bar chart in a WeChat Mini-Program using a canvas, this is my code:

```js
    function drawXaxis(ctx) {
        //绘制X轴横线
        ctx.setLineWidth(0.5);
        ctx.setLineCap('round');
        ctx.moveTo(chartOpt.axisLeft, chartOpt.axisBottom)
        ctx.lineTo(chartOpt.right, chartOpt.axisBottom)
        ctx.stroke();
        var width = (chartOpt.right - chartOpt.axisLeft) / chartOpt.barLength;
        var data = dataSet.xAxis.data;
        var title = dataSet.title.text;

        //绘制X轴显示文字
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var textX = (width * (i + 1)) - (width / 2) + chartOpt.axisLeft;
            ctx.setFillStyle(dataSet.xAxis.color);
            ctx.setFontSize(dataSet.xAxis.size);
            ctx.setTextAlign('center');
            debugger;
            ctx.fillText(data[i], textX, chartOpt.axisBottom + dataSet.xAxis.size + chartOpt.textSpace);
        }
    }
```

And here is the UI:

[image]

The problem is that the labels are too close.
So I want to make those labels vertical.
I read about the rotate function which can rotate the entire canvas, now I want to rotate just the text.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: hi pls put full reproducible code to help you  edit your post & add `chartOpt` & `data` to give you working code

Comment: maybe you  need to    use   `ctx.save()`  `ctx.restore()` methods